# Syntax to add "Attribute" variable in GitLab API documentation to a curl command

Tags: curl, gitlab

Using GitLab API documentation, I'm able to get the commits for a project.

*Curl Command*:

```
curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tc5W6MZSREQb6XLCZx5-" "http://192.168.8.200:8081/api/v4/projects/4/repository/commits/master"
```

*Sample Output*:

```
{
    "id": "79653d97fef4e0e202439b4fddc9833d8d24433a",
    "short_id": "79653d97",
    "created_at": "2019-06-18T05:37:54.000Z",
    "parent_ids": [
        "e571470e928418f73938e453da7d69c7d306b004"
    ],
    "title": "Update Jenkinsfile",
    "message": "Update Jenkinsfile",
    "author_name": "Administrator",
    "author_email": "admin@example.com",
    "authored_date": "2019-06-18T05:37:54.000Z",
    "committer_name": "Administrator",
    "committer_email": "admin@example.com",
    "committed_date": "2019-06-18T05:37:54.000Z",
    "stats": {
        "additions": 1,
        "deletions": 2,
        "total": 3
    },
    "status": "failed",
    "last_pipeline": {
        "id": 35,
        "sha": "79653d97fef4e0e202439b4fddc9833d8d24433a",
        "ref": "master",
        "status": "failed",
        "web_url": "http://example.gitlab.com/adl-dte/create-app/pipelines/35"
    },
    "project_id": 4
}
```

When I go through the GitLab API documentation for commits (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html), there is a table with different "Attribute"s. Can you show me the use of Attribute with an example?

For example, how to use "since" Attribute with above curl command?

Comment: You're already using the id, it's in the path. The others are query params.

Comment: Can you show me how to use Attribute "since"?

Comment: Add the query parameter to the URL. If you don't know how, look it up; it's not specific to GitLab.

Comment: For someone out there looking for the answer ---> 

curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tc5W6MZSREQb6XLCZx5-" "http://192.168.8.200:8081/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits/?ref_name=master&since=2019-06-12T00:00:00Z"

Comment: *＋1* for keeping the site tidy.

Answer (score 1):

For someone out there looking for the answer ---> curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tc5W6MZSREQb6XLCZx5-" "http://192.168.8.200:8081/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits/?ref_name=master&since=2019-06-12T00:00:00Z"